# API Rest ASP.Net Core 3.1 retornando erro 404 quando publicada

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, rest

Estou fazendo alguns testes com APIs em ASP.Net Core 3.1. Neste caso, estou usando Entity Framework para acessar o banco de dados e Identity Core para registrar e logar usuários.

Para isso, implementei o seguinte controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
        this._signInManager = signInManager;
        this._configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return $"AccountController :: {DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}";
    }

    [HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserToken>> Login([FromBody] UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userInfo.Email, userInfo.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return await GenerateTokenAsync(userInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Login inválido" });
        }
    }
```

Eu também tenho o método de registro neste controlador, mas isso não vem ao caso.

O problema em que preciso de ajuda: no modo de desenvolvimento, todos os serviços funcionam (login, registro e um Get de teste, que retornam apenas uma string, acessada em "api/account"). No entanto, quando publico meu projeto, apenas esse serviço Get de teste funciona. Quando tento acessar a API de login, recebo uma resposta 404 Não encontrada.

Caso faça alguma diferença, aqui está a chamada do método de login:

```
@inject HttpClient http
@inject NavigationManager navigation
@inject TokenAuthenticationProvider authStateProvider
async Task FazerLogin()
{
    try
    {
        var loginAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(userInfo);

        var httpResponse = await http.PostAsync("api/account/login", new StringContent(loginAsJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseAsString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var loginResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserToken>(responseAsString, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            await authStateProvider.Login(loginResult.Token);
            navigation.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        else
        {
            loginFalhou = true;
            Mensagem = $"Não foi possível realizar o login do usuário. (Erro: {httpResponse.StatusCode})";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        loginFalhou = true;
        Mensagem = $"Não foi possível realizar o login do usuário...";
    }

}
```

Usei o método PostAsync para poder verificar se a requisição foi bem sucedida. Mas também tentei implementar a chamada do login desta forma:

```
async Task FazerLogin()
{
    try
    {
        var loginResult = await http.PostJsonAsync<UserToken>("/api/account/login", userInfo);

        await authStateProvider.Login(loginResult.Token);
        navigation.NavigateTo("/");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

O erro sempre permanece.

[image: Error occurring when login service call using HttpClient.]

A única diferença que noto entre os serviços é que o serviço que funciona retorna apenas uma string. O login, o registro e outros controladores retornam uma Task>. Esse é o problema? Se sim, existe outra maneira de implementar o login?

Comment: Debugue o seu código e localize exatamente onde você está recebendo o 404, não seria aqui? `await http.PostAsync("api/account/login`??? Você tem certeza de que está servindo a aplicação na porta 91?

Comment: Sim, é neste local que ocorre o erro. Porém, depurando o código não ocorre o erro. Ele só ocorre quando publicado e hospedado (em produção). E sim, tenho certeza que estou servindo a aplicação na porta 91, pois quando requisito o serviço GET /api/account recebo resposta bem sucedida. O erro ocorre chamando o POST /api/account/login.

Comment: você reparou que o seu post é para `"api/...` e não para `"/api/..."`

Comment: Apenas no exemplo em que usei o http.PostAsync, no exemplo em que usei o http.PostJsonAsync está `/api/...`. Mas isso não influencia, a biblioteca HttpClient resolve a URL. Como comentei anteriormente, o curioso é que se eu requisitar pelo Postman o serviço GET /api/account, tenho sucesso na requisição. O erro 404 só recebo quando requisito o POST /api/account/login...

Comment: Todo caso, consegui resolver o problema. Circundei o serviço de login com um try catch e passei a retornar o stacktrace. Com isso reparei que o erro era na connecion string. Em modo de desenvolvimento não precisa passar o login e senha do banco, mas em produção isso é obrigatório. Obrigado pela atenção =D

Comment: Então acho que essa pergunta pode ser fechada ;)

Comment: A página ela existe no servidor, o retorno do teu método retorna para uma página existe no servidor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema. Eu circundei o serviço de login com try catch e comecei a retornar o stacktrace. Com isso notei que o erro estava na string de conexão, pois eu não havia informado o login e a senha do banco de dados. Afinal, no modo de desenvolvimento não é necessário inserir o login e a senha do banco de dados, mas em produção isso é obrigatório. Obrigado a todos pelas dicas = D